# Operator overloading with template question

Tags: c++

I'm unable to recognize the following forms of operator overloading, specifically with the template parameter involved.  I found this while reading an [article](https://hackernoon.com/what-exactly-is-nullptr-in-c-94d63y6t) on nullptr.  I do not see these forms on [cppreference overloading page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) either.

Can anyone explain these forms of overloading and what they are doing?

Thanks

```
struct nullptr_t 
{
    void operator&() const = delete;  // Can't take address of nullptr

    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const { return 0; }

    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const { return 0; }
};
nullptr_t nullptr;
```

Comment: This code is describing how nullptr work, but is not _actually_ how `nullptr` works.  `nullptr` is a keyword in C++ and is built-in to the language.

Comment: I'm confused by the template parameter `T` being used prefix `*` and then again in the second template member function.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: The two `T` parameters are unrelated, and could use different names.

Comment: @MooingDuck yeah, that's an equivalent code, although I've run into instances where nullptr keyword was emulated this way for compilers which were not 100% C++11-compliant (the lack of `nullptr`, variadic templates and proper range-based loop is more common than I'd like it to be). I suppose this also lacks some const qualifier, e.g. `constexpr`, in front of `nullptr_t nullptr;` and specializations for various functional in standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting simpler:

```
struct A {
    operator int() {return 3;}
};
void function() {
    A aobject;
    int value = aobject; //uses A::operator int()
    //value is now 3
}
```

`operator int` is a curious member function that allows the struct to be converted to an `int`.  It's very curious in that it's the only case in C++ that uses the return type in order to resolve which overloaded function to call, including that it can resolve template types.

```
struct A {
    operator int*() {return 0;}
};
void function() {
    A aobject;
    int* value = aobject; //uses A::operator int()
    //value now holds the value 0 (NULL)
}
```

This is the same thing, but now `A` can be converted to an `int*`. It is otherwise self explanatory.

```
struct A {
    template<class T>
    operator T*() { return 0; }
};
void function() {
    A aobject;
    short* value = aobject; //uses A::operator T*<int>()
    //value now holds the value 0 (NULL)
}
```

By making `A::operator T*()` a template method, we can make our class able to be converted to a pointer to *any* type.  This expands the options for what you can convert to. `operator T C::*() { return 0; }` is similar, but also allows conversion to pointers to any member of any class, which is very rare and advanced.

Comment: From what I've experienced so far, function template parameters are deduced from the functions passed arguments or the template arguments.  In this case, the user defined conversion operator type (which is a template parameter value) can be deduced implicitly as well.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes: Class conversion operators are the _only_ case in C++ where the return type is used in operator overloads, including template type deduction. But this also leads itself to some really neat tricks. I've reworded some sentences to make that clearer.

Comment: Is `T*()` the return type or member function name?  I was trying to invoke the `A::operator T*<int>()` explicitly as a member function call but was unable to find a way.Thanks

Comment: `template<class T> operator T*()` is a template, that can generate member functions at compile time.  It would generate `operator short*()` as one of many possible member functions.  I'm actually not entirely sure how to call a specific overload like that, but in general, you would merely use `static_cast<int>(aObject);`, or `int(aObject)` or `(int)aObject`

Comment: @notaorb  it's both, though technically language rules say that conversion operator doen't have return type. Its name is the return type. Or perhaps it is also an argument type, which would make this kind of deduction consistent with other cases.

Comment: Finally, what is this form `T C::*() ` in the user defined conversion?  It looks like a pointer to a member function that returns some type.  Thanks!

Comment: @notaorb `T C::*` is syntax for pointer to member of class C which got type T (T can be any type, including a function type).  This allows `nullptr_t` instance to be converted into any pointer to a class member. I was confused and delighted by simplicity when I saw this kind of syntax first time

Comment: This clears up alot.  I'm confused on assigning the pointer to member function an actual member function and created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63042172/assigning-pointer-to-member-function