# Assigning pointer to member function

Tags: c++

I'm following up on an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63039295/), however my question pertains to type issues.

How do I assign a pointer to member function `C::f()` to the `m` pointer?

Does the member function need to be static?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct nullpt_t {
    template<class T>
    inline operator T*() const { return 0; }
    
    template<class C, class T>
    inline operator T C::*() const { return 0; }
};
nullpt_t nullpt;
    
struct C {
    void f() {cout << "here" << endl;}
};
    
int main(void)
{
    int *ptr = nullpt;       
    void (C::*m)() = nullpt;
    // now assign m with member function f()?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is take a pointer to the member function and assign it:

```
m = &C::f;
```

This only applies to *non-static* functions. Static functions have no instance associated with them, so you can take a standard function pointer to them. (Pointer-to-member is special because you have to supply an instance to dereference the pointer. Note that you don't have to do this when invoking a static member function normally.)

```
struct C {
    void f() {cout << "here" << endl;}
    static void g() {cout << "here static" << endl;}
};

int main() {
    // Pointer-to-member-function (non-static)
    void (C::*m)() = &C::f;
    // Standard function pointer (static)
    void (*n)() = &C::g;
}
```

Comment: I think I'm getting confused because when I try calling `m();` the compiler has an error.  `called object type 'void (C::*)()' is not a function or function pointer`.

Comment: @notaorb You have to supply an object of type C on which to invoke the pointed-to function. You can't say `C::f()` either because there is no instance of C, and neither can you use a pointer-to-member without an instance of C. For example: `C c_obj; (c_obj.*m)();`. A pointer-to-member must always be dereferenced in combination with an instance of the containing type.

Comment: @cdhowie: This answer is great, but would be more complete if it also contained the syntax for calling the methods

Comment: @MooingDuck You're right – but the question was about getting a pointer to a method and assigning it to a variable, not about using it (invoking a method through a pointer). ;) Expanding answers beyond questions' range may lead to writing a programming manual. ;D